# Software to aid using camera as a scanner

Tags: camera, scanner, image-processing, digitization

I want to digitize some index cards with my camera. I'm looking for a program that would automatically fix geometry on the shots (as you would expect the cards come tilted on the picture).

I have [an app (droid scan lite)](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.trans_code.android.droidscanlite) on my android phone that does exactly that, but I would prefer to do it on my pc (the phone camera has poor quality and it's slow and focuses badly while I have a decent slr). If the program is open source it's an advantage, cross platform -- even more so.

Comment: The title is a bit deceptive, but I can't think of something better.

Comment: There used to be a website called Qipit that would do this exact thing, but it's gone now :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [CamScanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner) and I find it quite useful.